# what is the interpretation of the :label;N in below mentioned line

Tags: sed

What is the interpretation of `:label;N` and `b label` in the below mentioned command

```
sed -i ':label;N;s/\+.*\n.*\n//;b label' paired.fa
```

`piared.fa` looks like this

```
@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:1107:1493:57038/1:@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:2307:16619:181383/2
GAGCCCCGCTTCATCGCCGTGGGCTACGTGGACGACACGCAGTTCGTGCGGTTCGACAGCGACGCCGCGAGCCAGAAGATGGAGCCGCGGGCGCCGTGGAT:TCCATGAGGTATTTCTTCACATCCGTGTCCCGGCCCGGCCGCGGGGAGCCCCGCTTCATCGCCGTGGGCTACGTGGACGACACGCAGTTCGTGCGGTTCGA
+:+
@CCFFFFFHHHGHIIFIIJGHGGGHIIJFGGGG0AH>GEHFFFEED=?@BD?B?BABDDDDDDBBDBBDBDDDCBBDCDCCCCDDDDDDBBBBDBB5<B@C:@@CFFFFFHFHHHJJJJJIJJIIJJJJJIJJJJJJJGGIJEHEFDDBDDD@BBDBDDDEEDDDDBDDDDCDDDDDDDDDBD>BBDDDDDDDBDDDD5<BD@
@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:2307:16619:181383/1:@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:2307:7539:10902/2
CCCTCCTGCTCTATCCACGGCGCCCGCGGCTCCATCTTCTGGCTCGCGGCGTCGCTGTCGAACCGCACGAACTGCGTGTCGTCCACGTAGCCCACGGCGAT:GAGCCCCGCTTCATCGCCGTGGGCTACGTGGACGACACGCAGTTCGTGCGGTTCGACAGCGACGCCGCGAGCCAGAAGATGGAGCCGCGGGCGCCGTGGAT
+:+
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJIJIJJJJJJJJJJIJJJHGHHHHFFFFFCE?BBB<<07<@BB@C@A@ADBD;BDBDDACD95<9BDBBD@DDBCBBDDBDBBB@@9:CCCFFFFFHHHGHJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJIJHHFFFEEDCDDDB?BDDDDDDDDDDDBDDDDDDDDDDDDDCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD<BD?@
@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:2307:7539:10902/1:@HWI-ST963:188:C29Y5ACXX:4:1107:1493:57038/2
GCCTTCATATTCCGTGTCTCCTGGTCCCAATACTCCGGCCCCTCCTGCTCTATCCACGGCGCCCGCGGCTCCATCTTCTGGCTCGCGGCGTCGCTGTCGAA:GCCTTCATATTCCGTGTCTCCTGGTCCCAATACTCCGGCCCCTCCTGCTCTATCCACGGCGCCCGCGGCTCCATCTTCTGGCTCGCGGCGTCGCTGTCGAA
+:+
CCCFFFFFHHHHHIHHHIJJJIJJIJJJJIJJJJJJJIJJJJJJIIJIJJJIGIHIJJJGFDDBDDDDDDDDDDDDDEDDDDDD9@>B@@9@BB9><A8<@:@CCFFFFFHHGHHIGHGHIIGIJJDHHIJIHHIIIHIGGGHJGIJCEHEHHHJEHJIIJHFDDDDDD@DDDDDCDDCDDCDDDD799>B95<9<>.5:(8@
```

Comment: I suspect this is buggy code. What I believe is intended is to remove the line containing a `+` and the following line. However this does not take into account the end-of-file edge case. Another solution is `sed -i '/+/{N;d}' file` or if the edge case is not an error `sed -i '/+/{N;$!d}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `:label` is a label, meaning a place marker in the code.
2. `N` means read the next line in and add it, preceded by a newline, to the end of the current pattern space.

   Before execution of `N`, sed's pattern space holds whatever it holds.  After `N` is executed, it holds (a) what was there before, (b) a newline character, and (c) the next line as read from the file.
3. `b label` means branch to the location named `label`.

The net effect of this code is to look for lines containing a plus sign, `+`, and delete everything from that plus sign to the end of the next line after the one with the plus sign.

Comment: i am still not very clear. what is the need to use label . Cant sed -i 's/\+.*\n.*\n//g' paired.fa do the above thing

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA Normally, sed reads in __only one line__ at time.  The `N` and the looping are needed to read more than one line in so that it can do that substitution that you want.

Comment: can you please explain N in the above command in a more simpler way